# C#: Does String.Length walk the buffer every time or is it just returning a stored value?

Tags: c#, string

Not much else to add. Just wondering if anyone knew what the internals were doing for the String class in C#

Comment: The length is stored in memory

Comment: I'm pretty sure that's described in the class and property documentation

Comment: This is wild guess but `Length` is stored it wouldn't make sense to implement it the other way.

Comment: [Use the source Luke](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/security/securestring.cs,cc328b7859cbcecb)

Comment: [All you need to know](http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/General/Strings.aspx#memory), by the Skeet himself.

Comment: @HansPassant it is `SecureString` reference. In casual `String` Length is extern.

Comment: @spender All you need to know, and more! if you go to Skeet.

Comment: @pwas [System.String](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/string.cs,915) and its Length property.

Comment: Since `string` is immutable there is absolutely zero reasons to make `Length` property computation expensive (you say buffer, buffers have size, returning size of buffer is not *"walking"*). Do you have any concerns regarding it or **why** do you ask this question?

Comment: How walking buffer can result in finding string length?

Answer (score 1):

As explained in the article [Strings in C# and .NET](http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/General/Strings.aspx):

> Essentially, a string is a character array in memory, plus the length of the array and the length of the string (in characters). The length of the array isn't always the same as the length in characters, as strings can be "over-allocated" within mscorlib.dll, to make building them up easier.

So the length is stored (actually two length, bytes and chars), it is not computed each time.

Answer (score 1):

In the CLR, the length of the string (in chars and in bytes) is stored in memory so that the CLR knows how large the block of memory (array of chars) containing the string is. This is done upon creation of the string and doesn't get changed because the System.String type is immutable.

This might help: [Jon Skeet string article](http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/General/Strings.aspx)